# Hiding a left column in CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a number of `div` elements:

```
<main>
    <div id="top">Top</div>
    <div id="left">Left</div>
    <div id="right">Right</div>
</main>
```

which I would like to show in a grid:

```
┌─────────────────┐
│ Top             │
╞══════╤══════════╡
│ Left │ Right    │
└──────┴──────────┘
```

I would like to be able to hide one element and have the other fill its space.

```
┌─────────────────┐
│ Top             │
╞═════════════════╡
│ Right           │
└─────────────────┘
```

The columns are not evenly spaced. I have used the following CSS for the `main`  and `div#top` elements:

```
main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 3em 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 120px 1fr;
    border: medium solid #333;
}
div#top {
    grid-column: 1/3;
}
```

The problem is that when I hide the first `div` using `display: none`, the second one only occupies the original space of the first one.

How can I convince the second div to take up the whole row?

The snippet below illustrates the point.

**Note:** The question at [Make div fill up entire CSS grid's row when the other part is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45270736/make-div-fill-up-entire-css-grids-row-when-the-other-part-is-not-available#) asks something similar, but solution doesn’t work in my case. This is because my Left div has a set width.

```js
var left = document.querySelector('div#left');
var right = document.querySelector('div#right');

right.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  left.style.display = left.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 3em 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 120px 1fr;
  border: medium solid #333;
}

div#top, div#left, div#right {
  border: medium solid #999;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  margin: 4px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: .5em;
}
div#top {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}
div#left {

}
div#right {
  
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="top">Top</div>
  <div id="left">Left</div>
  <div id="right">Right: Click to Toggle Left</div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the JS just for the demo? On click, where the left element is set to `display: none`, why not also set the right element to `grid-column: 1 / 3`?

If that's not an option, then try flexbox, which can handle the situation cleanly and easily.

```js
var left = document.querySelector('div#left');
var right = document.querySelector('div#right');

right.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  left.style.display = left.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: medium solid #333;
}

div#top {
  flex: 1 0 90%; /* to allow space for margins; see note below */
}

div#left {
  flex: 0 0 120px; /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
}

div#right {
  flex: 1; /* fg:1, fs:1, fb:0 */
}

main > div {
  border: medium solid #999;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  margin: 4px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="top">Top</div>
  <div id="left">Left</div>
  <div id="right">Right: Click to Toggle Left</div>
</main>
```

**More Information**

Here's an explanation for `flex: 1 0 90%`:

- [Flexbox: 4 items per row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29546550/3597276) (in particular, see the bottom section of my answer)

Here's an explanation for the problem you're encountering with Grid:

- [Aligning grid items across the entire row/column (like flex items can)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50234112/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

Use display:flex

```js
var right = document.querySelector('div#right');

right.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   var left = document.querySelector('div#left');
   var shown= !(left.style.display == 'none') ;
   if ( !shown ) {
     left.style.display = 'block';
   } else {
     left.style.display = 'none';
   }
});
```

```css
main {
  grid-template-rows: 3em 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 120px 1fr;
  border: medium solid #666;
}

div#top, div#left, div#right {
  border: medium solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px #AAA;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 1em;
}
div#top {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}
div#left {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}
div#right {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="top">Top</div>
  <div id="left">Left</div>
  <div id="right">Right: Click to Toggle Left</div>
</main>
```