# Is this possible with CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css, layout, grid, css-grid

I want the "Next" button of this section to go full width when the other div has been taken away. I need the middle div to stay as part of the same container as I will be putting this in the middle in a media query for tablet / desktop.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item--1">Page 1 of 20</div>
  <div class="item item--2">Previous</div>
  <div class="item item--3">Next</div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px;">
  <div class="item item--1">Middle</div>
  <div class="item item--2">Next</div>
</div>

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.item {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
}

.item--1 {
  text-align: center;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}

.item--2 {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1fr;
}

.item--3 {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1fr;
}
```

https://codepen.io/chrismorrison/pen/xjjwxQ?editors=1100

Comment: In what part? there are two next's

Comment: Hi, the bottom section. The top section is how it should look when there are both next and previous buttons. However when there is only one next button I would like this to go full width rather than half.

Comment: I suggest having a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45070481/make-a-row-stretch-across-all-columns-in-css-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by **retaining the class** on the "Next" div (there seems little reason to change it) and the targeting it differently when it follows the "Previous" div using the **adjacent selector.** `+`

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.item {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
}

.item--1 {
  text-align: center;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}

.item--2 {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.item--3 {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}

.item--2 + .item--3 {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item--1">Page 2 of 20</div>
  <div class="item item--2">Previous</div>
  <div class="item item--3">Next</div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px;">
  <div class="item item--1">Page 1 of 20</div>
  <div class="item item--3">Next</div>
</div>
```

Frankly, a better solution would be flexbox like so. This works with both Previous and Next buttons *out of the box*.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 20px
}

.item {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
}

.item--1 {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}

.item--2,
.item--3 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item--1">Page 1 of 20</div>
  <div class="item item--3">Next</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item item--1">Page 2 of 20</div>
  <div class="item item--2">Previous</div>
  <div class="item item--3">Next</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item item--1">Page 20 of 20</div>
  <div class="item item--2">Previous</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you!

However, I would need it to work with the Previous button as well exactly the same way you have worked it out for the Next button. I hadn't thought of using the adjacent selector, would this be possible?

Comment: I kinds figured that would be the next question...and no. Personally I'd use flexbox. I'll amend the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I wanted to use grid because the page number would sit between the buttons on a larger media query, and would work without using negative margins for two rows. I possibly could do this with flex but it might be more complicated. I've updated the CodePen link.

Comment: That may not be as much of an issue as you might think, dont forget you can change the order of elements with flexbox. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/XqqRaa

Comment: True, I've stuck with my code for now as the rest of what I'm working on just now is using it. Thanks a lot for your help.