# Reordering items with CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm about to take my first baby steps with CSS Grid, having used Bootstrap plus Javascript for grids until now. What I want to start with is something which I know to be very simple, if I but knew how.

Let's say I have a bit of HTML like this:

```
<div class="container">
 <div id="a">Blah</div>
 <div id="b">Blurgh</div>
</div>
```

1. On desktop, I want a 2 column layout with block a on the left, block b on the right.
2. On mobile (using media query), I want a single column, with block b above block a (so, out of the normal order).

So what do I need to do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

CSS Grid provides multiple methods for achieving your layout, including *line-based placement*, *grid areas* and *the `order` property*. I'll post examples of the first two below.

[**Line-based placement**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45070481/3597276)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: .5em;
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@media ( max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 50px 50px;
  }
  #b {
    grid-row: 1;
  }
}

/* non-essential decorative styles */
#a     { background-color: lightgreen; }
#b     { background-color: orange; }
#a, #b { display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; font-size: 1.5em; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="a">A</div>
  <div id="b">B</div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0j56hykt/2/)

---

### [**`grid-template-areas`**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45459717/3597276)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: .5em;
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  grid-template-areas: " a b ";
}

#a { grid-area: a; }
#b { grid-area: b; }

@media ( max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-areas: " b " " a ";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 50px 50px;
  }
}

/* non-essential decorative styles */
#a     { background-color: lightgreen; }
#b     { background-color: orange; }
#a, #b { display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; font-size: 1.5em; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="a">A</div>
  <div id="b">B</div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0j56hykt/3/)

Comment: I used the 'grid-template-areas' solution, and it works fine. I assume I can just extend it if I have other placement requirements further down the line. Is there a way to effectively switch back to default ordering after this out-of-order placement, so that subsequent blocks are placed left-right in the two columns for desktop, and in a single column for mobile. Or do I have to specify everything with grid-template-area?

Comment: Excellent answer, it helped me too.

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way I believe is to use the CSS grid `order` property.
You can simply define which order the elements appear in by stating the order with number values.

Define the container element to be displayed `grid`, and then depending on screen size set `grid template columns` and set `order` of each item.

Alter screen size to see the result on mobile / desktop:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto; /* make each item sit side by side */
}

#a {
  background-color:green;
}

#b {
  background-color: orange;
}
  
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%; /* make each item span full width */
  }

  #a {
    order: 2; /* set this to appear second */
  }

  #b {
    order: 1; /* set this to appear first */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div id="a">Blah</div>
 <div id="b">Blurgh</div>
</div>
```