# Make grid 1st item full height

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to make the first item of a grid full height, like a fixed column, here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="cell">
  <div class="cell-50">column</div>
  <div class="cell-50">1</div>
  <div class="cell-50">2</div>
  <div class="cell-50">3</div>
  <div class="cell-50">4</div>
  <div class="cell-50">5</div>
  <div class="cell-50">6</div>
  <div class="cell-50">7</div>
  <div class="cell-50">1</div>
  <div class="cell-50">2</div>
  <div class="cell-50">3</div>
  <div class="cell-50">4</div>
  <div class="cell-50">5</div>
  <div class="cell-50">6</div>
  <div class="cell-50">7</div>
  <div class="cell-50">1</div>
  <div class="cell-50">2</div>
  <div class="cell-50">3</div>
  <div class="cell-50">4</div>
  <div class="cell-50">5</div>
  <div class="cell-50">6</div>
  <div class="cell-50">7</div>
  <div class="cell-50">1</div>
  <div class="cell-50">2</div>
  <div class="cell-50">3</div>
  <div class="cell-50">4</div>
  <div class="cell-50">5</div>
  <div class="cell-50">6</div>
  <div class="cell-50">7</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
.cell{
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px repeat(7, 1fr);
}
.cell-50{
  border:1px solid green;
}
.cell-50:first-child{
  background:tomato;
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
}
```

I have searched for this but only found solutions on making a column full width.
I can't add another div, I have to use the 1st div on my grid.

[JSFidle](https://jsfiddle.net/6bjc8tp9/3/)

**UPDATE**

This is answered by Hodrobond in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052336/make-a-grid-item-span-to-the-last-row-column/44052563?noredirect=1#comment93464878_44052563) from  in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052336/make-a-grid-item-span-to-the-last-row-column).
Here is the solution https://jsfiddle.net/s6qz4fkx/

Comment: I need to have the 1st cell full height, not the last one, that's the difference with that answer.

Comment: Hodrobond's solution is not working if I use grid-gap