# Understanding grid negative values

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a grid that has a full span row at the bottom.

For full span columns I can use `grid-column: 1/-1`.

For single span columns I can use `grid-column: 1/1`.

For single span rows I can use `grid-row: 1/1`.

**But if I want to define the last column or row, I have to write `grid-column: -2/-1`.**

Why is the syntax not the same as with 1/1 for the first column/row? Or am I making a mistake somewhere?

I also made a jsfiddle to demonstrate my problem: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4b79an5r/)

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5px 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(50px, 2fr) 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 15px;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 1fr;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  grid-column: 2/-1;
  grid-row: 1/1;
  justify-content: center;
}

.border-left {
  background: purple;
  grid-column: 1/1;
  grid-row: 1/-1;
}

.border-bottom {
  background: #410266;
  grid-column: 2/-1;
  /* grid-row: -2 / -1;  this will work, -1/-1 will not */
  grid-row: -1 / -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="header"> HEADER </div>
  <div class="border-left"></div>
  <div class="grid-item">1 </div>
  <div class="grid-item">2 </div>
  <div class="grid-item">3 </div>
  <div class="grid-item">4 </div>
  <div class="border-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `-2` or `2` ? ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif i dont understand your question. -1/-1 does not work, -2/-1 does work. 1/1 and 2/2 also work. Why does -1/-1 not work is my question

Comment: in your code I don't see any `-2` so I am asking if you meant `2` instead

Comment: i updated the jsfiddle with a commented out -2 at the spot. The code has -1/-1 and so the bottom border is not displayed. changing it to -2/-1 displays the bottom border, hence my question

Comment: @Paulie_D, although there is some overlap between this question and the duplicate, they are not the same. This question is more about Grid error handling.

Comment: @Michael_B there is actually no overlap at all, since spanning is NOT the issue here (i even wrote how its done in my question). I will update the question to make it very clear...

Comment: @Michael_B Fair enough.. I *bow* to the Master ☺

Answer (score 8, accepted):

when using the same value inside `grid-column`/`grid-row` you will fall into this rule:

> If the placement for a grid item contains two lines, and the start line is further end-ward than the end line, swap the two lines. **If the start line is equal to the end line, remove the end line.**<sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#grid-placement-errors)</sup>

So saying `grid-column:-1/-1` means `grid-column:-1` which is `grid-column:-1/auto`

> `auto`
>
> The property contributes nothing to the grid item’s placement, indicating auto-placement or **a default span of one**. (See § 8 Placing Grid Items, above.)

So basiclly you said to your element to start at the last line and span one column which will create an implicit new column:

A basic example to illustrate:

```css
.box {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:20px 20px 20px;
  grid-auto-columns:100px;
  grid-gap:5px;
}

span {
  grid-column:-1/-1;
  height:40px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

[image]

You can see that the span is having `100px` which means it create a new column inside the implicit grid and is not inside the explicit one defined by `20px`

When using `-2/-1` it's clear that you will consider the *before the last* and the  *last* line and the element will be placed in the last explicit column:

```css
.box {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:20px 20px 20px;
  grid-auto-columns:100px;
  grid-gap:5px;
}

span {
  grid-column:-2/-1;
  height:40px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

[image]

Same logic apply when using positive value but you won't notice a *strange* behavior since you will most likely span an explicit column thinking it's correct to specify, for example, `grid-column:1/1`

Answer (score 9):

The `grid-column` and `grid-row` shorthand properties *count grid lines*.

*You wrote:*

> For single span columns I can use `grid-column: 1/1`

This doesn't make any sense. It resolves to:

```
grid-column-start: 1
grid-column-end: 1
```

So you're defining a column that goes from the starting line to the starting line.

A column has a starting line and an ending line. So to span the first column you use:

```
grid-column: 1 / 2
```

The only reason your code works as you expect is because the [Grid error handling algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-placement-errors) removes the end line when the start and end lines are equal.

So `1 / 1` resolves to `1 / auto`, where [`auto` represents a default span of 1.](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-placement-auto)

---

*You wrote:*

> But if I want to define the last column or row, I have to write `grid-column: -2/-1`

Yes, that's one way to do it. (You can also use positive integers, since you know the number of columns.)

---

*You wrote:*

> Why is the syntax not the same as with 1/1 for the first column/row? Or am I making a mistake somewhere?

### 1 / 1

As mentioned above, `1/1` was invalid. It is fixed by the Grid system, resolving to `1 / auto`. As a result, you span the first column.

### -1 / -1

This combination of values is also invalid. It means *span from the last line of the grid to the last line of the grid*. Grid error handling changes the end value to `-1 / auto`. This takes you out of the explicit grid (because an implicit column is created) and [negative values no longer apply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44053668/3597276). The negative values end where the implicit grid begins ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5ye4cxjt/)).

### `-2 / -1`

Correct syntax. So it works. Span one column starting from the penultimate line of the grid.