# How to span a grid cell across all dynamic rows?

Tags: css, css-grid

The attached example works properly, the first child of `.container` is spanned across all rows, but the problem is that the `grid-row-end` value is dependent on a number of children of `div.container`. Is it possible to do it without the magic constant (4) and WITHOUT changing an HTML structure. Unfortunately using `grid-row-end:-1` is possible only for the explicit grids.

```css
    .container {
        display:grid;
        grid-gap: 0.4em;
    }
    .container > * {
        background-color: lightgray;
    }
    .container *:first-child {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-row-end: 4;
    }
    .container *:not(:first-child) {
        grid-column: 2;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>IMG</div>
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was asked already https://stackoverflow.com/q/44052336/383904

Comment: if you remove the gap properie and dispatch margin on the childrens (standing in the second column and from the second row, you can set a hudge value that the possible numbers will never match or be at the most the same amount

Answer (score 0):

> This was asked already [Make a grid item span to the last row / column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44052336/383904)  **- Roko C. Buljan**

> if you remove the `gap` propertie and instead dispatch `margin` on the children (standing in the second column and from the second row, you can set a hudge value that the possible numbers will never match or be at the most the same amount of actual rows of the grid  **– G-Cyrillus**

the linked question did not take into account the gap set.

snippet *drawing* of my comment:

```css
.container {
        display:grid;  
    }
    .container > * {
        background-color: lightgray;
    }
    .container *:first-child {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-row-end: 100;/* use a value that will over the expected numbers of row */
        grid-gap:0; /* empty rows will collapse to none height */
        grid-auto-rows:auto; /* do not give an height here , else empty rows will use space */
        margin-right:0.2em;
    }
    .container :nth-child(2)   {
        margin-left:0.2em;
        grid-column:2;
    }
    .container :nth-child(2) ~ div  {
        grid-column:2;
        margin-top:0.4em;
        margin-left:0.2em;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>IMG</div>
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

Edit

If javascript is okay with you

```js
let rowsToSpan = document.querySelectorAll(".container>*");
rowsToSpan[0].style.gridRowEnd = rowsToSpan.length
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.4em;
}

.container>* {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.container *:first-child {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  /*grid-row-end: 4;*/
}

.container *:not(:first-child) {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>IMG</div>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
</div>
```

inspired from https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pRYPwK

Comment: Thank you. I also found the solution with grid-row-end:BIG_NUMBER. It is not a nice solution, I will have to find a different solution...

Comment: @LiBorecek a different solution is to use javascript to set the right amount of rows to span ... you did not use the javascript tag, would that be your other option ?

Comment: Yes, I used javascript to set the grid-row-end value. I wanted to solve it only with CSS. The CSS Grid layout is very powerful, I am surprised that it cannot solve so simple case.

Comment: @LiBorecek *un* -fortunately, CSS is not meant to look through the dom to rewrite or update a few rules. The browser , while rendering the dom structure and its content will also apply the CSS selectors that matches the dom elements (if it can/if it is valid) . There is no way to select a parent for instance or to update a colspan/rowspan attribute nor to count the nunber of elements it founds, it can increase a counter (CSS counter) but is not aware of that value and cannot reuse it elsewhere. **That's a tipycal javascript job** even if `span all` seems awfully missing in the spec ;)