# How override align-content property in grid-container

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid container .grid-container
with the specified properties

```
.grid-container { 
   display: grid;
   heigth: 500px; //for example
   align-content: start;

}
```

inside the container the number and type of elements are not defined (they come from the server)
one of the elements is a grid element with the class .file-viewer

```
.file-viewer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

indicating height at 100%; in .file-viewer I hoped that it would take a height of 500px from the parent

But this doesn't happen because of **align-content: start;**
The question is how can I override the behavior of **align-content: start;** inside a child grid element
I need that the child grid element occupies the entire height of the parent element so that align-content: start; remained at the grid container

I tried setting the grid container property
**grid-auto-rows: 1fr;**

and the child *.file-viewer* set
**grid-row: 1 / span 1;**
this works as it should for the *.file-viewer*, but if other elements come from the server it does not work as it should

please help me how to override
align-content: start; and make the grid element occupy the entire height of the grid container

thanks in advance

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052336/make-a-grid-item-span-to-the-last-row-column-in-implicit-grid

Answer (score -1):

```
.grid-container {
grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}
.file-viewer {
grid-row: span 1; 
}
```

Comment: I have tried setting the grid container property grid-auto-rows: 1fr;